# Android - set badge for Android (Samsung)

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have this function for Samsung's badge notification from [this link](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/blob/master/ShortcutBadger/src/main/java/me/leolin/shortcutbadger/impl/SamsungHomeBadger.java)

```
     private static final String CONTENT_URI_S = "content://com.sec.badge/apps?notify=true";
     private static final String[] CONTENT_PROJECTION_S = new String[]{"_id","class"};


    public static void setBadgeSamsung(Context context, int count) {

        Uri mUri = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI_S);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Log.d ("badge" , "------2------------" );
            cursor = contentResolver.query(mUri, CONTENT_PROJECTION_S, "package=?", new String[]{context.getPackageName()}, null);
            Log.d ("badge" , "------2-1111-----------" );
            if (cursor != null) {
                String entryActivityName = getLauncherClassName(context);
                boolean entryActivityExist = false;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Log.d ("badge" , "------2-3-----------" );
                    int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    Log.d ("badgeID" , Integer.toString(id) );
    //                    ContentValues contentValues = getContentValues(badgeCount, false);
                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put("badgecount", count);
                        contentResolver.update(mUri, contentValues, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
                        if (entryActivityName.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("class")))) {
                            Log.d ("badge" , "------2-3-4----------" );
                            entryActivityExist = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!entryActivityExist) {
                        Log.d ("badge" , "------2-3-4-5---------" );
    //                    ContentValues contentValues = getContentValues(badgeCount, true);
                                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                                            contentValues.put("package", context.getPackageName());
                                            contentValues.put("class", getLauncherClassName(context));
                                            contentValues.put("badgecount", count);
                        contentResolver.insert(mUri, contentValues);
                    }
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                Log.d ("badge" , "------2-3-4-5-6--------" );
                cursor.close();
        }
      }
   }
```

Actually , I get crash with this log:

```
D/badge   (31741): ------2------------
F/art     (31741): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception 'java.lang.SecurityException' thrown in unknown throw location
F/art     (31741): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to NewStringUTF
```

Any suggestion to solve it?

**EDITED :**

I added this to *AndroidManifest.xml* :

```
<!--for android badge-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

<!--for Samsung badge-->
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"/>

</activity>
```

Comment: Have you taken Permission?

Comment: It looks like those permissions might be inside `<activity>` tags. If so, you need to move them to outside of the `<application>` tags.

Comment: @PratikButani I changed it , it's not crashing now , Although it's not setting any badge.

Comment: add `catch` in between `try` and `finally` and see what logs printing.

Comment: @PratikButani it didn't go to catch

Comment: Do you use samsung device?

Comment: Yes of course, I use Samsung s5 (Android 5)

Comment: @PratikButani I've tested on Google Launcher and it wasn't worked. :| 
Actually, it's okay on Samsung's default launcher.